# Proving that a solution of a system vanishes in the whole manifold or non vanishes in the whole manifold

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M^{n}$ be a connected Riemaniann manifold. Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be a orthonormal frame of vector fields on $M$. Consider the following linear first-order system of differential equations

\begin{cases}
X_1(Q)=\omega(X_1)Q\\
X_i(Q)=0, \quad 2 \le i \le n,
\end{cases} where $\omega $ is a $1$-form in $T^{*}M$ (dual of the tangent bundle). Let $Q \in C^{\infty}(M)$ be a solution of the system.

My question is: What should I use to show that $Q=0$ on $M$ or $Q \ne 0$ on $M$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $Q(p)=0$ for some $p\in M$, and choose an arbitrary $q\in M$; it will suffice to show that $Q(q)=0$. Let $\gamma:(a,b)\to M$ be a smooth path with $[0,1]\subset(a,b)$, $\gamma(0)=p$,
and $\gamma(1)=q$, and let $f(t)=X^1(\dot{\gamma}(t))\omega(X_1(\gamma(t)))$. Note that $Q\circ\gamma$ satisfies the initial value problem
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(Q\circ\gamma)(t)=f(t)(Q\circ\gamma)(t) \\
(Q\circ\gamma)(0)=0
$$
Clearly $(Q\circ\gamma)(t)=0$ is a solution, and by the Picard-Lindelöf theorem, it is the *unique* solution. We must therefore have $(Q\circ\gamma)(1)=Q(q)=0$.